# one virtual serial port with socat

Tags: python, pyserial, socat

how to create just one virtual port with socat?

I want to test pyserial to read and write via one port

I'm already try :

```
socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=1 pty,raw,echo=1
```

it creates two virtual ports /dev/pts/9 and /dev/pts/10

when I'm try:

```
ser.write('test\n')
```

in another console, I'm try to read :

```
ser2.readline()
```

when timeout, pyserial read '\n' as '^J'

Answer (score 4):

`^J` is the same as `\n`, see [Wikiepdia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character). I cannot reproduce the blocking you experience:

```
$ socat -d -d pty,raw,echo=1 pty,raw,echo=1
2012/06/14 14:29:13 socat[28866] N PTY is /dev/pts/3
2012/06/14 14:29:13 socat[28866] N PTY is /dev/pts/5
2012/06/14 14:29:13 socat[28866] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

Terminal 1:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/5')
>>> s.readline()
'hello\r\n'
>>> s.readline()
'hello\n'
```

Terminal 2:

```
>>> import serial
>>> s = serial.Serial('/dev/pts/3')
>>> s.write('hello\r\n')
7
>>> s.write('hello\n')
6
```

The `readline()` calls return as soon as I execute write in the other terminal.

Comment: I'm using /dev/pts/9 to write and read via two terminal, im success to write data to /dev/pts/9, but failed to read the data in another terminal. In your example you using two, but i want use just one port(dev/pts/9)

Comment: @Alvin serial does not work that way, you need two ports which are virtually connected